# How to display a table segregated by dates in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, enumerable

Using Enumerable, I am trying to display dates in an organized event calendar by dates. Not as a standard 7 grid calendar.

Trying to get:

December 1, 2011
Event 1
Event 2
Event 3

December 2, 2011
Event 4
Event 5

December 3, 2011
Event 6

...

Currently Enumerable confuses the hell outta me. Thanks for any guidance--

EDIT Dec.22,2011

Current Data:

Controller string-

```
@events = Event.where('start >= ?', Date.today).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
```

View call-

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <table stuff here>
<% end %>
```

Method- Have not specified anything enumerable on method as of now---

My table includes the following fields; :title, :venue, :address (is geocoded), :about (text), :start (datetime function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for question update**: So you have a bunch of event objects in `@events` so you could use a [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
@events_by_date = @events.group_by { |e| e.start.to_date }
```

That would give you a Hash in `@events_by_date` with dates as the keys and arrays of Event objects as the values.

Then you'd want an array of arrays of Dates to match your month and drive the table from that array:

```
<table>
    <% @month.each do |week| %>
        <tr>
            <% week.each do |day| %>
                <td>
                    <% if day %>
                        <%= day.day %>
                        <% @events_by_date[day].to_a.each do |e| %>
                            <%= e.about %>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                </td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

There would be some formatting involved of course but the structure would be similar.

Comment: Um. Im completely flustered about now. You have a link to an intro article on this so I can know how to use it to interact with my data from a novice/intermediate programming point of view?

Comment: @keade: Sorry, I don't know of any introductory material on this stuff, I just read the manual to learn it. Maybe you should include more information on what data you're starting with.

Comment: Makes sense- I accept answer, but am not at dev comp, will let you know when it works- thanks for the help @mu!

Comment: @keade: I think it would make sense to add a helper to generate that table, something like `event_table_for '2011-12', @events`; that would probably be a lot cleaner than doing it all in ERB.